# Error adding Google Analytics' URL Tracking Parameters to an internal website search query

Tags: google-analytics, url-parameters

I'm trying to add Google Analytics' URL tracking parameters to a recently redesigned website

The original URL:

https://www.funakoshi.co.jp/searches?search_type=searchAntibody&keywords=GTX127375

Adding campaign parameters:

https://www.funakoshi.co.jp/searches?search_type=searchAntibody&keywords=GTX127375&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=GeneTex_Funakoshi_Adwords

You should notice that the appended parameters are affecting the internal site search. In the original search URL, there are two results returned. When the URL/campaign parameters are added, the search result is null.

I've noticed the site's internal search isn't affected until the = is added after "*&utm_source=*"

So

https://www.funakoshi.co.jp/searches?search_type=searchAntibody&keywords=GTX127375&utm_source

Still returns the two results for the internal site query and

https://www.funakoshi.co.jp/searches?search_type=searchAntibody&keywords=GTX127375&utm_source?

Does not.

Why might this be the case? Any help here would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks in advance. 
Patrick

Comment: Is there anyone out there

Comment: There's currently an undisclosed bounty of never-ending love and appreciation